# how to reformat jQuery / JS function properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can't figure out how to write this as a function without the jQuery

This works & returns what I need:

```
   var state = $('#order_ship_address_attributes_state_id option:selected').text()
```

Which is the text from an options list aka "Florda" instead of "3534"

```
<option value="3534">Florida</option>
```

However, I would like it written in this convention instead:

```
 var city = ((document.getElementById('order_ship_address_attributes_city')||{}).value)||"";
```

... to match the rest of my variable declarations.

Trying this but error read "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null"

```
var state = ((document.getElementById('order_ship_address_attributes_state_id option:selected')).text())
```

Can't figure out the correct way to write this — any help would be much appreciated : )

Comment: ,text is still a jquery method. If you want to not use query, you gotta not use jquery.

Comment: I think you are looking for vanilla js alternative to your jquery. If so, try `document.querySelector('#order_ship_address_attributes_state_id option:selected').textContent;`

Comment: @benvc is partially correct, it should be `option:checked` like this `document.querySelector('#order_ship_address_attributes_state_id option:checked').textContent`

Answer (score 0):

As @benvc pointed out. You want to use `.textContent` instead of calling the `.text()` jquery method.